# plot geodata on the globe perspective in R

Tags: r, plot, r-sf, geo

(how) is it possible to plot geodata – for example a polygon layer – on a globe with d3/perspective view, similar to [this graphic](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Europe_on_the_globe_(red).svg) on wikipedia?

I'd like a solution with `sf` and `ggplot` most, but any solutions are welcome.

(I ask this mostly out of curiosity, but since I see graphics like this fairly often, I guess the question might be useful)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use orthographic projection in `sf` and `ggplot2` projecting to `"+proj=ortho"` coordinate reference system.

Making the oceans turn blue may take some tweaking; I have resorted to buffering the Null Island by the Earth radius (inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fzenoni/ef23faf6d1ada5e4a91c9ef23b0ba2c1)).

For more information of the arguments (i.e. lat_0 & lon_0) used have a look at the PROJ documentation https://proj.org/operations/projections/ortho.html

For a more graphic example consider this piece of code:

```
library(sf)
library(giscoR) # for the countries dataset only
library(ggplot2)

# projection string used for the polygons & ocean background
crs_string <- "+proj=ortho +lon_0=30 +lat_0=30"

# background for the globe - center buffered by earth radius
ocean <- st_point(x = c(0,0)) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 6371000) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = crs_string)

# country polygons, cut to size
world <- gisco_countries %>% 
  st_intersection(ocean %>% st_transform(4326)) %>% # select visible area only
  st_transform(crs = crs_string) # reproject to ortho

# one of the visible ones red (don't really matter which one :)
world$fill_color <- ifelse(world$ISO3_CODE == "DEU", "interesting", "dull")
   
# now the action!
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = ocean, fill = "aliceblue", color = NA) + # background first
  geom_sf(aes(fill = fill_color), lwd = .1) + # now land over the oceans
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("interesting" = "red",
                               "dull" = "lightyellow"),
                    guide = "none") +
  theme_void()
```

[image: ortographic view of world countries, with germany in red]

Answer (score 2):

That is amazing @jindra-lacko! I took the liberty of checking the code above by creating a polar view map of Antarctica (holy grial of maps ;)), and works amazingly!:

```r
library(sf)
library(giscoR) # for the countries dataset only
library(ggplot2)

# Test of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70756593/7877917

# projection string used for the polygons & ocean background
crs_string <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0"

# background for the globe - center buffered by earth diameter
ocean <- st_point(x = c(0, 0)) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 6371000) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = crs_string)

# country polygons, cut to size
world <- gisco_countries %>%
  st_intersection(ocean %>% st_transform(4326)) %>% # select visible area only
  st_transform(crs = crs_string) # reproject to ortho

# one of the visible ones red (don't really matter which one :)
world$fill_color <- ifelse(world$ISO3_CODE == "DEU", "interesting", "dull")

# background for the globe - center buffered by earth diameter
ocean <- st_point(x = c(0, 0)) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 6371000) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = crs_string)

# now the action!
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = ocean, fill = "aliceblue", color = "black") + # background first
  geom_sf(aes(fill = fill_color), lwd = .1) + # now land over the oceans
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(
      "interesting" = "red",
      "dull" = "lightyellow"
    ),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(
    title = "Polar View: Antarctica",
    caption = "Based on Jindra Lacko:\nhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/70756593/7877917"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your kind words! it is not _quite_ perfect (the polygon of Antarctica is "cut out" slightly at antimeridean - which is a known feature of the gisco dataset) but it looks neat, doesn't it? :)