# sf::st_transform() returns empty geometry

Tags: r, r-sf, coordinate-systems, map-projections

I have transformed the rnaturalearth countries dataset for orthographic plotting using the procedure outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/fzenoni/ef23faf6d1ada5e4a91c9ef23b0ba2c1).

[image]

However, transforming with `st_transform()` results in at least one of the geometries (mainland Russia) being empty.

This reads and attempts to transform the problematic polygon:

```r
polygon <- st_as_sf(data.frame(st_as_sfc(readLines("https://pastebin.com/raw/APH15G6X"), crs = 4326)))
st_transform(polygon, "+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs")
```

```r
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields (with 1 geometry empty)
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
CRS:           +proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
            geometry
1 MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
```

The geometry seems to be valid and is expected to be fully visible after orthographic projection, so I'm not sure what else could be going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist you linked is inspiring, and it has helped me a lot in the past. But it is rooted in an obsolete version of `{sf}` - and with release 1.0 (which introduces S2 backend for geographic CRS) things got somewhat easier.

I have updated the logic somewhat and published it a while back in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70756593/7756889 - when I amend the code to your definition of Ortho projection it shows mainland Russia as expected (= the geometry is not empty, but cut somewhat to hide the invisible parts in Asia). In addition the answer uses the world dataset from Gisco instead of Natural Earth; it should have negligible impact.

```
library(sf)
library(giscoR) # for the countries dataset only
library(ggplot2)

# projection string used for the polygons & ocean background
crs_string <- "+proj=ortho +lat_0=20 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs"

# background for the globe - center buffered by earth radius
ocean <- st_point(x = c(0,0)) %>%
  st_buffer(dist = 6371000) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = crs_string)

# country polygons, cut to size
world <- gisco_countries %>% 
  st_intersection(ocean %>% st_transform(4326)) %>% # select visible area only
  st_transform(crs = crs_string) # reproject to ortho

# now the action!
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(data = ocean, fill = "aliceblue", color = NA) + # background first
  geom_sf(fill = "lightyellow", lwd = .1) + # now land over the oceans
  theme_void()
```

[image: ortho map with russia behaving itself - I wish it were so in real life as well...]